# Why are these primitives containing $\arcsin x$ equal up to a constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-trigonometric-functions

While trying to solve $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{14x-x^2}\;dx$, I obtained three different primitives in three different ways:

Method 1: completing the square

$c(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left[49\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x}{7}-1\right)+(x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}\right]$

Method 2: using the substitution $x=u^2$

$s(x)=49\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{14}}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}(x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}$

Method 3: Wolfram

$w(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}-49\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x}{14}}\right)$

At first, I thought some mistakes were made, as I was not able to reconcile the different appearances of the $\arcsin(\cdot)$ terms. After some inspection using Desmos, it turns out all 3 functions are equal up to a constant. In fact, they are separated by an amount of $\dfrac{49\pi}{4}$:

All three functions (without $+C$):
[image]

All three functions (with the appropriate $+C$):
[image]

So at this point, I'm pretty much convinced all three methods agree and are valid. However, I would like to know **how exactly one can prove the $49\pi/4$ spacing (or $49\pi/2$ depending on which functions are compared) between each primitive, other than using this graphical method, which is much weaker after all**.

Bonus 1: why is it that each method leads to a different primitive *a priori*?

Bonus 2: what method was used to obtain $w(x)$ (Wolfram's primitive) if not the other two?

Thanks in advance for all your input!

Comment: For each arcsin, draw a triangle and use trig identities.

Comment: The spacing: evaluate $s(0)$, $c(0)$, and $w(0)$.  Since two antiderivatives differ by a constant (by a vertical shift of graph, by a function that is sent to zero by differentiation), you can extract that constant by evaluating at the same input.

Comment: Re: Bonus 1: Why do you believe that the different constants are deducible *a priori*?  I am aware that some (more obscure) trigonometry identities were found by antidifferentiating by different methods, but this doesn't mean that the *constant* is what is different at the end.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you! I did the computations and found the shifts. However, does this prove that the shift between functions is the same for all $x$? I'm more interested in understanding how I could go from one form to the other. For instance, if I get the primitives $\log(2x)$ and $\log(x)$ for another integral, I can just say $\log(2x)=\log(2)+\log(x)$ and absorb $\log(2)$ in the constant to show that both $\log(2x)$ and $\log(x)$ are valid primitives. Can I do something similar with $\arcsin(x)$ with these examples? The question is more about the inverse trig than the integration.

Comment: Given two antiderivativers (two things that differentiate to the same thing), they can only differ by a fixed constant.  (That constant can be zero.)  (If not, their difference is a function of $x$, but that function differentiates to zero, so ...)

Comment: @EricTowers Relative to the Bonus 1 question, perhaps I'm being unclear. I meant to ask why is it that two different methods lead to two different-looking functions. It's not obvious to me that $\dfrac{49}{2}\arcsin(x/7-1)+C=49\arcsin(\sqrt(x/14))$ for some constant $C$. How can I ensure that this is true to convince myself I did not make a mistake in either calculations, without resorting to Desmos? That is really what I want to know.

Comment: @EricTowers Ah, it seems we posted both our last comments at the same time, so I did not see yours until now. If I understand you correctly, one way to check would be to differentiate the difference of both primitives I suspect are the same (up to a constant) and if the result is $0$ for all $x$, then it is settled. I just tried it and it worked. I would be satisfied with this, but are you aware if there are any direct ways to prove that both primitives are the same up to a constant (such as in my log example), without resorting to taking the derivative of the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting the common part $\frac12 (x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}$. From the original integral, $0\le x \le 14$.

Let $c_1 = c(x) - \frac12 (x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}$, where $-\frac{49\pi}{4} \le c_1 \le \frac{49\pi}{4}$.

$$\begin{align*}
c_1 &= \frac12 \cdot 49\arcsin\left(\frac x7-1\right)\\
\sin\left(2\cdot\frac{c_1}{49}\right) &= \frac x7-1\\
\end{align*}$$

---

Let $s_1 = s(x) - \frac12 (x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}$, where $0 \le s_1 \le \frac{49\pi}{2}$.

$$\begin{align*}
s_1 &= 49\arcsin\sqrt{\frac x{14}}\\
\sin^2\left(\frac{s_1}{49}\right) &= \frac x{14}\\
\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{s_1}{49}\right) &= 1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{s_1}{49}\right) = 1-\frac x7\\
\sin\left(2\cdot\frac{s_1 - 49\pi/4}{49}\right) &= \sin\left(2\cdot\frac{s_1}{49}-\frac\pi2\right)\\
&= -\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{s_1}{49}\right)\\
&= \frac x7-1
\end{align*}$$

So taking $c_1 = s_1 - \frac{49\pi}4$ would match the behaviours of $c$ and $s$.

---

Let $w_1 = w(x) - \frac12 (x-7)\sqrt{14x-x^2}$, where $-\frac{49\pi}{2} \le w_1 \le 0$.

$$\begin{align*}
w_1 &= -49\arcsin\sqrt{1-\frac x{14}}\\
\sin^2\left(-\frac{w_1}{49}\right) &= 1-\frac x{14}\\
\cos\left(-2\cdot\frac{w_1}{49}\right) &= 1-2\sin^2\left(-\frac{w_1}{49}\right) = \frac x7 -1\\
\sin\left(2\cdot\frac{w_1 + 49\pi/4}{49}\right) &= \sin\left(2\cdot\frac{w_1}{49}+\frac\pi2\right)\\
&= \cos\left(2\cdot\frac{w_1}{49}\right)\\
&= \frac x7-1
\end{align*}$$

So taking $c_1 = w_1 + \frac{49\pi}4$ would match the behaviours of $c$ and $w$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The relation between $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ leads to a relation between $\arcsin $ and $\arccos$ of corresponding arguments. Then the formula connecting $\cos (2t)$ and either $\cos t$ or $\sin t$ leads to a relation that lets us rewrite $\arccos$ for an argument in terms of $\arccos$ for half of argument (or double of it, seen reciprocally).

---

Details:
Let us denote by $X\in[0,1]$ the value $x/14$ (for $x\in[0,14]$), then by $t$ the value of the arcsine computed in $\sqrt{X}=\sqrt{x/14}$. We want to show in the world of functions taken **modulo constants**:
$$
\frac 12\arcsin\left(\frac x7-1\right) \equiv
-\arcsin\sqrt{1-\frac x{14}} \equiv
\underbrace{\arcsin\sqrt{\frac x{14}}}_{=t} \qquad
\text{ modulo constants ,}
$$
or in other words
$$
\frac 12\arcsin\left(2X-1\right) \equiv
-\arcsin\sqrt{1-X} \equiv
\underbrace{\arcsin\sqrt X}_{=t} \qquad
\text{ modulo constants ,}
$$
Then $\sin t=\sqrt X$, $\sin^2 t=X$, $\cos^2 t=1-X$, $\cos t=\sqrt {1-X}$, $t=\arccos\sqrt{1-X}$.
The last equivalence is now traced back to the case that the functions $\arccos$ and $-\arcsin$ differ by a constant.

So we want in fact:
$$
\frac \pi 2-\frac 12\arccos\left(2X-1\right) =
\arccos\sqrt{1-X} =
\underbrace{\arcsin\sqrt X}_{=t} \ ,
$$
and we get also get rid of the (module of) constants.
Note that when $X$ varies in $[0,1]$, $\sqrt X$ and $\sqrt {1-X}$ take values in the same intervals, $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ of such values are in the interval between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Also the left most term takes values in this interval. For $X=0$ we obtain the common value zero. For $X=1$ we obtain the common value $\frac \pi 2$. Since the cosine is bijective seen as a function on $[0,\pi]$ to $[-1,1]$ the equality between the left most and the other terms, both equal to $t$, is equivalent to the the one obtained after applying the cosine on twice these terms. We compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos\color{brown}
{2\cdot\left(\frac \pi 2-\frac 12\arccos\left(2X-1\right)\right)}
&=
\cos\left(\pi-\arccos\left(2X-1\right)\right)\\
&=-\cos\arccos\left(2X-1\right)\\
&=-(2X-1)\\
&=1-2X\ ,\\[3mm]
\cos \color{brown}{2\cdot t}
&=1-2\sin^2 t\\
&=1-2(\sqrt X)^2=1-2X\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the terms in brown are equal.

$\square$

Answer (score 1):

**Bonus 2**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sqrt{14 x-x^2} d x 
= & \int \sqrt{14 x-x^2} d(x-7) \\
= & (x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2}-\int(x-7) \frac{14-2 x}{2 \sqrt{14 x-x^2}} d x \\
= & (x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2}-\int(x-7) \frac{7-x}{\sqrt{14 x-x^2}} d x \\
= & (x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2}-\int \frac{14 x-x^2-49}{\sqrt{14 x-x^2}} d x \\
= & (x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2}-I+49 \int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{14 x-x^2}} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging yields
$$\int \sqrt{14 x-x^2} d x 
= \frac{1}{2}(x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2}+\frac{49}{2} \underbrace{\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{49-(x-7)^2}}}_J$$
For the integral $J$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{14 x-x^2}} d x 
= & \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{14-x}} dx\\
= & -2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{14-(\sqrt{14-x})^2}} d(\sqrt{14-x}) \\
= & -2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{14-x}}{\sqrt{14}}\right) +C\\
= & -2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{14}}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back gives WA’s answer
$$\int \sqrt{14 x-x^2} d x 
= \frac{1}{2}(x-7) \sqrt{14 x-x^2} -49 \sin ^{-1} \sqrt{1-\frac{x}{14}}+C $$